# The best away to install Sharepoint on a production machine

Tags: sharepoint-designer, configuration

On my computer I already have Visual Studio and Sharepoint Designer, I am missing the server. What would the best away to install it and to start learning how it works?

Should I use a virtual machine, try to install it directly, what kind of setup would be best?

Comment: It depends on multiple factors. What OS is your machine running ?

Comment: I have a Win 8.1 running on an i5 CPU and 8 GB of RAM

Comment: the answer of @Ulrich Bojko is the way I recommand. Create a new Virtual machine and install SharePoint on windows server edition. You can do it on Windows 8.1 but this will not ensure you a good behavior of SharePoint.

Comment: I have done that, right now Win Server 2012 with Sharepoint is running on a Hyper-V virtual machine. Now I'm trying to use the Sharepoint Designer that I have on Win 8.1. I need to find a way to connect to the server on the virtual machine.

Comment: You can create a virtual switch on Hyper-V so you can create a bridge between the two machines.

Comment: Now when I try to create a site it says that the server must be running Sharepoint foundation

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of guide online, i found these two sites has a good article explaining about the sharepoint installation.
 http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2009/11/07/installation-procedure-for-base-sharepoint-2010-install-part-1-of-2/

and the Todd Klindt's Posts are very usefull too http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=320

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a test- or developerbox I would (and always do) create a virtual machine, then install SharePoint using the "Standalone" option.

Read how here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263202.aspx

Visual studio needs to be on the same machine as your SharePoint installation. SharePoint Designer does not.

Then when you have played around with your Standalone SharePoint you can go ahead and install a production machine. For that you need a minimum of two virtual machines.

1. SQL
2. SharePoint FE (FrontEnd)

Do NOT install Visual Studio or SharePoint Designer on your production. That could led you in a lot of trouble later on.

If you absolutely only have one machine available, install SharePoint and SQL on the same machine (NOT recommended for PROD).

Here is how: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262243.aspx